# My command is not working, error var is not defined

Tags: tkinter, command, var

I have a main window, which open up another window by clicking on RFFE, inside this window i have a combobox which contains 'Fix pattern' and 'Random Pattern' which is connected to the print button, but everytime I click print it comes up with error var is not defined please help.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        RFFE = Button(self, text="RFFE", command=self.rffe_button)
        RFFE.pack() 

        quit = Button(self, text="QUIT", command=self.quit)
        quit.pack()


    def rffe_button(self):
        var = RFFE()


def RFFE():
    Up = Toplevel()
    Up.geometry('470x280')  
    top_label = Label(Up, text='RFFE', font=('calibri', (14))).pack()

    var = StringVar()   
    Sequence_menu_label = Label(Up, text='Trigger Sequences', font=('calibri', (14))).pack()    
    Sequence_menu = OptionMenu(Up, var, 'Select','Fix pattern','Random Pattern').pack()

    var.set('Select')

    Print = Button(Up, text='Print',command=callback).pack()


def callback():
    print "You've selected: " + var.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Main(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `var` is a local variable bound to the scope of the method `RFFE`. In order to use variables between methods you either need to pass the variable in as an argument, or make the variable an instance variable or global variable.

Since the functions aren't part of the class you'll need to make them global. Insert `global var` in the places where you use `var`.